# Accessing returned scope method variables in another method in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an Angular app with a service and a controller:

**service.js**

```
.factory('MyService', function ($http, $q) {
    var api_url = 'http://localhost/api/';

    var MyService = {

        list: function (items_url) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http({method: 'GET', 
                url: api_url + items_url}).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    defer.resolve(data);
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    defer.reject(status);
                });
            return defer.promise;
        },
        ...
   }
});
```

**controller.js**

```
.controller("ItemsCtrl", function ($scope, MyService) {

    $scope.getItems = function () {
        MyService.list('items/').then(function(data) {
            $scope.items = data;
        });
    };

    $scope.addItems = function () {
        $scope.getItems();

        // why is this undefined ??!!!
        console.log($scope.items); 
    };
```

The issue is that I want to call the `$scope.getItems` method inside the `$scope.addItems` method. Do I perhaps need to use `$scope.apply()`, as the returned value is a promise?

I think what I am displaying here is a general lack of understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your controller like this:

```
.controller("ItemsCtrl", function ($scope, MyService) {

    $scope.getItems = function () {
        return MyService.list('items/').then(function(data) {
            $scope.items = data;
        });
    };

    $scope.addItems = function () {
        $scope.getItems().then(function() {

          // should be what you want this time
          console.log($scope.items); 

        });
    };
```

Your problem is when you call `$scope.getItems()`, http response is not returned yet, so `$scope.items` is not populated. You have to wait for all the promises are resolve to access `items`.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.items` is undefined because `$http` is an **asynchronous** communication. That is, when you call `$scope.addItems()`, it creates and sends the request to retrieve your list of items, then immediately moves on to the next line of code, which is to log `$scope.items` to the console. Since there's nothing in `$scope.items` yet, you get an undefined value.

If you want to operate on the data returned by the http call, you must guarantee that the data will be populated. In other words, any operations you want to perform on `$scope.items` should be called within your `.then()` block.

`$scope.$apply()` is used when you are not executing within an AngularJS context, to force the AngularJS framework to evaluate the expression. It will not help you here - you'll get an "$digest already in progress" error, or something along those lines.

Try this:

```
.controller("ItemsCtrl", function ($scope, MyService) {

  $scope.getItems = function () {
    MyService.list('items/').then(function(data) {
      $scope.items = data;
      console.log($scope.items); 
    });
  };

  $scope.addItems = function () {
    $scope.getItems();
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `$scope.getItems` is asynchronous. Your callback (that added via then) is called after `$scope.addItems` executed.